# How to make nested lists out of flat list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested

Need to turn this example list

```
list = ["Hello","world","!!!"]
```

Into nested lists like this

```
new_list = ["Hello",["world",["!!!",None]]]
```

For any kind of flat list given . Somehow I can make a flat list out of nested lists , but after hours of trying I can't seem to find the solution by myself or by googling . I've searched here but nothing comes out for this specific problem.

Thanks in advance and sorry if it is a stupid question .

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Maybe they're fond of Lisp and want to implement [cons cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can use recursion:

```
l = ["Hello","world","!!!"]
def to_list(d):
  return None if not d else [d[0], to_list(d[1:])]

print(to_list(l))
```

Output:

```
['Hello', ['world', ['!!!', None]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an iterative solution:

```
def to_nested(seq):
    result = [seq[-1], None]
    for item in reversed(seq[:-1]):
        result = [item, result]
    return result


l = ["Hello","world","!!!"]
print(to_nested(l))
# ['Hello', ['world', ['!!!', None]]]
```

which basically constructs the target nested list by starting from the end of the input list and keep replacing itself with a list consisting of the previous element and its *earlier* self.

---

## EDIT

Time-wise this is more efficient than the recursive method proposed in [@Ajax1234's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59359514/5218354):

```
def to_nested_r(seq):
    return None if not seq else [seq[0], to_nested_r(seq[1:])]


%timeit to_nested(l * 100)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 19.2 µs per loop
%timeit to_nested_r(l * 100)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 167 µs per loop
```

Additionally, `to_nested_r()` may hit the maximum recursion limit for larger inputs:

```
to_nested_r(l * 1000)
```

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

while, `to_nested()`, being an iterative implementation, is not restricted by recursion limitations and the following:

```
to_nested(l * 1000)
```

runs just fine.